# How to put hash after hostname (before path) in browser address bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On my site I am using ajax to get elements of the page. When I do this, I am simply adding the address to the hash in address bar. But this generates links that don't look so good, in example, when user wants to go to `hostname.com/path`, my javascript puts in the address bar something like this: `hostname.com/path#/path`.

Recently I saw on my local social network site, that it is possible to manipulate the path part of the link. The site I am talking about, is somehow modifying everything after the first `/`. So when I am entering `mysocialsite.com/path`, it erases the `/path` part and replacing it with `#/path`. How can I do this? As fas as I knew, it is not possible to modify URL (besides # part), but apparently I was wrong.

**Edit:** This is exactly what I want to do:

1. I am going to `somepage.com/path/to/resource`. Typed that in my
   address bar and clicked enter.
2. Now page has loaded, and the javascript on that page changed the link to `somepage.com/#path/to/resource`, without doing any further page reloads or any similar stuff.

Comment: search for htaccess rewrite rules.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for [pushstate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history):

```
var infoToStoreIfYouNeedThis = { foo: "bar" }; // might not need this at all
history.pushState(infoToStoreIfYouNeedThis , "Title of new page", "/#newLocation");
```

That will change the url to "domein.ext/#newLocation" without reloading the page. If you goto */#anotherLocation* and then press the browsers back, you go to /#newLocation.
Carefull though, not IE9 and lower, [supportchart can be found here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=history)

If you dont mind the reload (which you probally do):

```
window.location = "/#newLocation"
```

Comment: @Martijn: It is definitely doing something. :) But as far as I can tell, this is not modifying the path part of address bar. I will add further description of what I wanna do to my main post. Anyways thank you for that.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can.  There is nothing stopping you from having a controller to handle `/`, and then client-side code to handle `#` afterwards.  Note that you can't get rid of the initial `/`, but you can do something like:

```
http://example.com/#/path/segment2/segment3
```

Comment: Okay but how? (of course we are talking about changing `http://example.com/path/segment2/segment3` to `http://example.com/#/path/segment2/segment3`)

Comment: @ojek, What do you mean, how?  You just don't use those paths.  Use the root path for everything except other resources that you want at other paths.  I don't know what you are asking.  This involves changes server-side, and you've not told us what you are using server-side.  Usually rewrite rules, but it depends on the architecture of your application.

Comment: I only want client side of this. Now, lets say I am going to `http://example.com/path/segment2/segment3`. I entered this in my address bar, and loaded the page. Now what I want, is that javascript on my page will automatically add hash here: `http://example.com/#/path/segment2/segment3` without doing any page reloads or any similar stuff.

Comment: @ojek, `window.location`  However, you're talking about going to a new page, which requires HTML5 history functionality or loading a new page.